# Cannot import "from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor"

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

The libraries used
python : 3.7.16
transformers : 4.24.0
tensorflow : 2.4.1

I am triyng to convert tensorflow wav2vec model into tflite in colab

`from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor`
for this line it gives a error cannot load the wav2vec2Processor.
`from transformers import TFWav2Vec2ForCTC` also the same error
the error message is follows;

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)
   1075         try:
-> 1076             return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1077         except Exception as e:

19 frames
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenizers.tokenizers'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)
   1076             return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1077         except Exception as e:
-> 1078             raise RuntimeError(
   1079                 f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
   1080                 f" traceback):\n{e}"

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.wav2vec2 because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'tokenizers.tokenizers'
```

but
`import transformers` dosent produce any error

but
`transformers.Wav2Vec2Processor` gives the same above error

I want to find out how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

at first Update transformers to the latest version:

```
!pip install transformers --upgrade
```

Check dependencies: like your Error  `No module named 'tokenizers.tokenizers'`

```
!pip install tokenizers
```

after you install the dependencies Restart the runtime and cheak it

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor
```